# Creating a 2D matrix from 2 FITS images of unequal dimensions for Radio/FIR correlation

Tags: radio-astronomy, astropy

I have two images of NGC 6946:

```
item       description        size (pixels)    scale (arcseconds/pixel)
 1.     70 micron MIPS FITS     241 x 241           4.5 
 2.     20 cm VLA FITS          512 x 512           2.0
```

I need to create a matrix with 2 columns (70 micron vs 20 cm), where each column will store the values at each pixel in such a way that the central pixel coordinate of each image coincides, so that I can plot for Radio/FIR correlation.

How should I perform such task in python?

Comment: I've added the `astropy` tag on the off chance that it will apply. Do you want to interpolate one image to fit the other, since their pixel sizes aren't 1:1? Will you need to rotate one image to match the other as well? I reformatted a bit, feel free to edit further or roll-back.

Comment: Thank you for formatting my question. I will keep this method in mind. Returning to the problem at hand, I want to create a 70 micron intensity (Jy) vs 20 cm intensity (Jy) plot and fit a curve through those points.

Comment: Right, you are hoping for pixel-for-pixel matching so that you can look for a correlation. They have different scales, so you'll need to at least interpolate first, since the pixel scales are different, (roughly 9:4). Is there some rotation difference, or are they both oriented exactly the same way (e.g. North = up)?

Comment: Do the images have world co-ordinate system (WCS) in their headers?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I have already done it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the WCS for both images, you can use the [astropy reproject module](https://reproject.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Once you have projected image 1 onto image 2, the `(x,y)`th pixel from the output will correspond to the `(x,y)`th pixel from image 2.

Then you can [flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) both images with numpy, and assemble them into a 2-column array.